# Regex in Calculator with Wrong Answer

Tags: ruby, regex, calculator

The code below is intended to be a calculator script that I can run against a mathematical expression. The output is obviously wrong. I think it is infinitely looping. If anyone can find errors in here, I'd be really appreciative.

I cannot use `eval` in my solution. The general format you see here is what I have to use. I'm also 99% sure that I cannot use a `case` statement either.

**The Code**

```
expression = (ARGV[0]).gsub(/\s/, '')
def theCalculator (expression)
  while expression =~ /\D/
    if expression =~ /\(.*\)/
        expression = expression.scan(/\((.*)\)/)
        expression = $` + (theCalculator(expression)).to_s + $'
    elsif expression =~ /\^/
        expression = expression.scan(/(\d*|\d*\.\d*)(\^)(\d*|\d*\.\d*)/)
        expression = $1.to_f ** $3.to_f
        expression = $` + expression.to_s + $'
    elsif expression =~ /\*|\//
        expression = expression.scan(/(\d*|\d*\.\d*)(\*|\/)(\d*|\d*\.\d*)/)
        if $2 == "*"
          expression = $1.to_f * $3.to_f
        else
          expression = $1.to_f / $3.to_f
        end
      expression = $` + expression.to_s + $'
    elsif expression =~ /\+|\-/
      expression = expression.scan(/(\d*|\d*\.\d*)(\+|\-)(\d*|\d*\.\d*)/)
        if $2 == "+"
          expression = $1.to_f + $3.to_f
        else
          expression = $1.to_f - $3.to_f
        end
      expression = $` + expression.to_s + $'
    end
end
return expression
end
expression = theCalculator(expression)
puts expression
```

**The Input**

```
ruby calc.rb "2 ^ (4 - 1.0) + 1"
```

**The Output**

```
(big ol infinite loop)
```

Comment: `^` has special meaning in Bash, which is what I am assuming your shell is.  You need to escape it `\^`.

Comment: @squiguy Are you referring to the input string?

Comment: Yes, when you type your calculation on the command line.

Comment: in my case it is going to forever loop,not ended

Comment: I suppose it's obvious, but regex "parsing" has got to be the *worst* possible way to write a calculator.

Comment: @squiguy Actually in this case it's okay, since it is taken in as a string. (I looked at that and showed it to my professor, he confirmed it will not be an issue) Thank you for noticing that, though. I'll definitely use that knowledge in the future.

Comment: @DigitalRoss I agree, and I just edited my original post to include the fact that we CANNOT use the EVAL function in Ruby.

Comment: @RubyLovely Can you elaborate as to why it'll loop forever? What isn't ended?

Comment: how you got that output? i m confused

Comment: @RubyLovely I may have posted an updated version of the code. I'll just delete what I get for output, because it currently loops over and over

Comment: Do people just run through posts and downrank them for the hell of it? Why is my question being voted down?

Comment: I suspect they have too many points and are trying to burn some off. Every time they down vote it costs them a point too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good place to start would be this [resource on regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/). Also know that there are several online regex evaluators should you feel the need to experiment this way.

Just giving several very important tips, which should bring you closer to finishing your assignment yourself:

- find a way to debug your code! You already know `puts`, you can use that to start with
- look carefully at your `while` condition (`\D`): in my opinion `[^\d.]` is better
- also, in my opinion `[*\/]` and `[+-]` can replace `\*|\/` and `\+|\-` respectively
- in your recursive call, I get better results adding `.to_s` to `expression`
- watch out for the greediness: <strike>use the *lazy* quantifier for the parens match</strike>
  **Edit**: use an expression to match parens without any inner parens…
- `\d*|\d*\.\d*` is not the same as `\d*(?:\.\d*)?`

Please look carefully at the above list and try to understand my suggestions.
Can you get your script to give the same result as I get? (`9.0`)

Comment: What a fantastic explanation! THank you so much! Solved SO many problems!